# How to the soft keyboard in my win phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

No success with
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().TryHide();

Comment: Did you look here too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679406/how-to-hide-windows-phone-8-1-soft-keyboard-effectively

Comment: If you did find a way to do it, Microsoft would more than likely not accept your application for the store

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard appears when the the user can enter some input, eg when a textbox has the focus. The hide the keyboard set the focus to an element the doesn't accept input like a dropdown or a disabled textbox.